# How to properly justify migrating a question to Programmers?

Tags: discussion, migration

I had flagged that [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25252906/315052) might benefit from being migrated to the Programmers StackExchange, which was declined. I didn't provide a rationale in the flag notice, but it was based on questions that I had previously answered that were later migrated ([this one](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/256222), and [that one](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/209729)). The question was subsequently closed about an hour after I posted the flag.

So, what triggered my reasoning to migrate was that the question was actually less about writing a program, but more about the rationale for language design of extending the semantics of `struct` (as opposed to merely adding a new `class` construct with object semantics).

Was I wrong to suggest migration? Should I always supply my reasoning with the migration request? If so, how much justification should be provided?

Comment: upvoted for the 200% correct approach to use flag instead of [dumping misleading comments like "belongz to Programmaz"](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/a/6840/31260)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When a question is closed as one of the standard not off topic reasons (too broad, opinion or unclear) or as a resource request (Programmers.SE has the same close reason), it is unlikely that it would be able to get migrated to Programmers.SE and not be rejected for the same reason.

The question in question:

> It seems to me that C++-style `struct` can do more things than a C-style `struct` (for example, you can have member functions and access specifiers). What's the design reason for this, considering we already have `class` in c++?
>
> A real design example would be appreciated.

> closed as primarily opinion-based by Pascal Cuoq, Matt McNabb, Ed Heal, George Stocker♦

So, we've got the opinion based question along with a resource request in there (a design example).  This wouldn't be a good candidate as is for Programmers.SE.

---

Furthermore, a question can't be migrated without special SE Dev buttons if it is older than [60 days](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/151890/213963).  SE employees can do it for outstanding questions that now belong on a different site or special circumstances.  This typically involves an outstanding question that is under threat of deletion on the origin site but would be on topic on the other (I've seen some go from SO or P.SE to Software Recommendations).  This is also what happened with the MSO/MSE split and old SO specific questions where migrated here.

That said, the question was posted on August 11th.  That is older than the 60 day window.  Mods can't migrate it even if they wanted to.

---

If you really do want something migrated from SO to P.SE you need to act promptly on it (don't wait a week or month) and establish your credentials on P.SE to the mods so that they are aware that someone with familiarity with the site is suggesting it.  Mods get lots of "this belongs on P.SE" when it isn't a good question nor is it on topic on P.SE.  A message such as:

> Please migrate this to Programmers.SE. The core question here is a design one rather than a code one. The correct answer will describe the full stack and significant changes from the structure the OP has currently described (which frankly makes me shudder). I have 30k rep on P.SE and will endeavor to make it not be a rejected migration. – MichaelT Dec 1 at 3:50   helpful

Note the description of why it is off topic on SO, why it would be on topic on P.SE, the nature of the answer and the credentials.  For that question, as soon as it was migrated I fixed up some edits on it, up voted it, and provided what I consider to be a rather good answer - the question remains open.

Comment: Thanks. I was only seeking clarification now, I had posted migration earlier. So, the justification is going to the P.SE moderators, that is good to know.

Comment: @jxh its still going here, and you need to tell the mods *here* that you know what you are doing *there*.  The rejection rate for SO to P.SE migrations is 22%.  One out of five migrations is rejected - and those are *all* mod initiated.  You need to show that it won't be another of those.