# Migrating questions to Software Engineering (previously known as Programmers)

Tags: support, migration

There are some questions which are better suited to [Programmers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) rather than Stack Overflow.

Do we need special privileges to migrate questions to this site? I am not able to see it in migration list.

Comment: Yes, you need to be a moderator. Which questions were you thinking of? Programmers.SE has a bit of a problem with its image on SO so when it was a migration option, there was lots of unsuitable stuff going through.

Comment: There are many questions that are related to designs/ design patterns/ architecture related. Such questions are posted on Stackoverflow since it is much more popular than programmers.stackexchange.com 
Such questions are generally closed on stackoverflow, for being opinion based. But are important. When I tried to move it to programmers, It was not in the list.

Comment: You don't seem to have much activity on the programmers site. "Opinion based" is still a close reason over there.

Comment: So what is a good stackexchange site to discuss design decisions?

Comment: The stack exchange network isn't built for facilitating discussion. Not every type of content will find a home here.

Comment: okay, so what is a good stackexchange site where a question related to design decision can be asked?

Comment: Just flag it as needing moderator attention and state that it needs migrating and where and why. I've done this a few times now and they've responded quickly.

Comment: highly related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/281390/458741 and http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261016/458741

Answer (score 9):

There used to be a non-moderator migration path from StackOverflow to Programmers(current name: Software Engineering), but it caused an influx of simply bad questions being migrated there instead of closed/deleted.

See: [Please stop using Programmers.SE as your toilet bowl](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/73382/223467)

If you come over a question you think would be **really** appropriate for Programmers, you could raise a custom flag and alert a moderator to its presence.