# Can we drop TeX as a migration recommendation option in favor of Code Review or Software Engineering SE?

Tags: feature-request, migration

I may be missing something but I've seen plenty of posts that would be better fits for Code Review SE or Software Engineering SE, but I can't remember the last time I've seen a post about LaTeX. It seems like it would be a good idea to replace TeX as an option for migration with either Software Engineering SE or Code Review SE.

Comment: Two probable reasons for the downvote. Since your post is a [feature-request], someone who does not want this _feature_ to get implemented downvoted this post. Second possible reason is that you may not have searched for questions similar to your post. You can see some in the 'Related' posts sections, such as, http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/311348/, http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/266749/, http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251652/. Disclaimer: I am not the downvoter :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No.  We have had issues in the past with users [migrating absolute *garbage* to Software Engineering](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300346/migrating-questions-to-programmers-se) and [users not really understanding](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253975/be-careful-when-recommending-code-review-to-askers) when to migrate to Code Review, so allowing users to just migrate *any* ol' question they think is suitable over to those sites is a *bad* idea.

The team may revisit the migration targets to see if LaTeX is still viable, but don't anticipate the path to Software Engineering or Code Review becoming unblocked anytime soon.

Comment: This is a good point, I have read [complaints](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73382/please-stop-using-programmers-se-as-your-toilet-bowl) about people suggesting migrating lousy questions to Programmers SE come to think of it. Would that be an issue for Code Review though? I can see how Software Engineering SE could become a dumping ground for "anything that's too broad for Stack Overflow" though.

Comment: Would it help if the migration options included summaries - e.g. "Code Review (for feedback requests for existing, working code)."

Comment: No, given that again, this would rely *heavily* on users being successfully able to identify on-topic and good Code Review questions, which is a feat that still eludes many.

Comment: Couldn't we simply introduce a rep threshold for migration requests to CR, i.e. 5k or something like that?

Comment: @Seth only if that was a rep on a "target" site. I know for sure that neither 5K at SO nor 10K+ rep at Programmers helped me when I made [totally stupid assumptions about posts being acceptable for CR.SE](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/268722/839601 "'...I made the same mistake as you did, recommended CR.SE for a question that didn't match. One of their regulars was kind enough to refer me there (if memory serves they also dropped a few f-words when pointing it but after reading that list I kinda understood why)'")

Comment: @gnat Hm. I think we could go either way about this, but in general (just an assumption) I'd say that 10K+ users ***should*** by now be able to know only to flag when they're sure. What I'd find interesting would be a threshold that'd either require 10K+ on Stack Overflow, or 2K (or something like that, as Code Review is "smaller" than Stack Overflow) on Code Review. I don't know how feasible a threshold like that'd be though, and I don't know how the Code Review community would think about a threshold like that, as they're the first ones that should be asked. Just guessing here :D

Comment: @Seth I did the wrong suggestion about CR.SE (_very_ wrong as I have later learned) mentioned in prior comment when I was well above 10K at Programmers, long past this mark. You may of course believe that 10K at SO somehow magically make one know better than same amount of rep at Programmers...

Comment: @gnat Hm... I guess it'd be better to go the safe route then =/ Either CR rep requirement, or no migration option for CR.

Answer (score 8):

You've missed a step here. The first thing you should do is ask on [Code Review SE's Meta](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/) and [Software Engineering SE's Meta](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/) whether they would be supportive of being such a target. Don't forget to search first as it's quite likely this has come up before for both of these sites.

If their active users don't want this, we shouldn't impose it on them.